# Programmatically access addressing of ad hoc network?

Tags: macos, unix, networking, wifi, ip-address

I'm testing this using my laptop to create the ad-hoc network.

I would like to be able to programmatically access the unique mac ids of any other chips in the area similar to a router.

Any kind of file logging would work, if that's what it needs to be. The perfect set up would be an evented set up that on discovery of a new mac address, or rediscovery of an address. A script would run, passing in the id.

Can anyone one help me figure out where one would look, or atleast point me in a good direction to figure it out? Thanks!!

Comment: Routers don't deal with MAC addresses, they deal with IP addresses. And you won't have IP addresses unless those other wireless devices join your network.

Comment: @greg How does my home router do mac address filtering, and lots of other functions related to mac addresses?

Comment: Well, your home router is both a layer 2 and a layer 3 device. MAC addresses matter at layer 2.

Comment: @greg The hardware running my ad hoc network cannot operate as a layer 2 device?

Comment: I didn't say that. You said "...similar to a router", but I was just pointing out that the usual function of a *router* is as a layer 3 device. What we call a "router" today (especially a home router) is usually both layer 2 and 3. Unfortunately, while I'm splitting hairs over here I'm not really helping answer your question, so I'll end here.

Comment: @greg Ah, ok I see what you're saying. Thanks for the clarification, so the addressing layer is different then the routing layer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "programmatically access the unique mac ids of any other chips in the area"?  Are you looking for a list of mac-addresses?  Do you want to make some kind of connection and exchange data?

Comment: Any kind of file logging would work, if that's what it needs to be. The perfect set up would be an evented set up that on discovery of a new mac address, or rediscovery of an address. A script would run, passing in the id.

Comment: @MikePennington not sure what happened just now that answer got deleted I guess... It's will be a number of iPhones, the setup should realize when one vs another is within range - the program responds differently depending on the id of the phone (who's it is) and the goal is no action needed to be taken on the phone.

Comment: @fancy, my answer would not work for your requirements.  Be sure to put that last comment in your original question so other people know from the beginning what you're asking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arp -a` to see the current ARP table which gives you all devices that your computer has talked to (their IP and MAC addresses). You can filter by interface if you're interested only in a particular network/device.